# Why does a ListView cause rendering error when used directly inside Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used ListView inside Column and it causes a rendering error. When I wrapped ListView in Container or Expanded widgets, it works fine. What is the reason that causes the error?

```
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        
        Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: use shrinkWrap: true property on listview

Comment: @Boby there is no error, this is the working code, i just wanted to know the reason behind it that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ListView tries to fill all the available space given by the parent element (here column). But the column has no definite space defined.

Column's children should have a definite size. If you haven't used Expanded or shrinkWrap property of listview, it won't recognize. Hence will give you rendering error.

With Expanded, you defined that child can expand as much as it wants, giving the definite size.

Or

If you set it to `shrinkwrap: true`, the list will wrap its content and be as big as its children allow it to be.

So in both cases, the column will get a definite size to render.

Comment: shrinkwrap property is specific to ListView or other widgets also allow it?

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava yes, it is specific to Listview